# access to array elements

Tags: javascript

When I write this

```
        var table = document.getElementById("tableKon");
        var rowlen = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowlen);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var dkkTo = [0.13,0.17,0.17,1,15.43,0.98,1.15,0.16,0.11,0.18,8.34];
```

an then for exapmle

```
        cell1.innerHTML = dkkTo[0];
```

it gives me NaN in the column.

Comment: It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/pkGry/

Comment: The error must be elsewhere, that code works.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Are you sure there is a table with an ID of "tableKon"?